# Unable to dowloading PDF with restrictions

Tags: pdf, adobe, restrictions

I'm trying to download some PDF's from http://www.jre.co.jp/news/20160630.html (note, you must use IE to open the pdfs for some reason). However, whenever I download them, I get a blank pdf (with the right number of pages) or a pdf which say's I cannot download the document on each page (again with the right number of pages).

I checked the permissions and there is no Document Open password, but there is a permissions password. I've tried unlocking the permissions using PDFUnlock!, but still just get a blank document.

Could somebody point me towards a method for downloading the pdf? I find it odd that I can view the pdf online, but not download it.

**Edit:** I'd also appreciate if somebody could explain how the website is stopping me from downloading the pdfs.

Comment: Opening a PDF in Firefox from that website, I see the text for a brief instance, and then it all turns white.  Something must be masking it.

Comment: The first PDF "Table of Contents" PDF (160630evaluation_document00.pdf) appears non-conformant. For example, indirect object 142 0 R at byt offset 95501 has a /BaseFont entry with a name value with unescaped control characters (outside the ASCII range '!' .. '~').

Comment: @E.O. Download restriction most likely related to PDF permissions. `pdfinfo 160630evaluation_document00.pdf` ... `Encrypted: yes (print:no copy:no change:no addNotes:no algorithm:RC4)`. Can bypass, e.g. `wget http://www.jre.co.jp/news/pdf/160630evaluation_document00.pdf`